# Why is Stack Overflow in read-only mode?

Tags: support

Anyone know what the issue is with Stack Overflow currently? It has been in read-only mode for a few minutes already so I am wondering what is going on.

Does it have to do with the failover test this weekend?

---

Update: the services are back again now. Thanks for that! What was the reason of the break?

Comment: There was some information of the failover test on Meta Stack Exchange. I think this was in the community bulletin board too for a few days.

Comment: @AlonEitan The website was down, the banner said "look here for the status", but the links didn't provide an answer, which is why OP asked the question.

Comment: The question is asking what was the cause of the outage. How can that be 'not reproduced'?

Comment: This is similar to typo questions getting closed solely for being about typos despite clearly being helpful to future readers. The emphasis is on "**can no longer be reproduced**", so voters think questions should be closed on that basis alone regardless of what is actually being asked.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "this" being the outage, or the closure? (for clearer communication, always say what "this" and "that" is.)

Comment: Just went readonly again for a few minutes, related this this perhaps?

Comment: Quoting Oded _This was not scheduled - people are looking into the causes._

Comment: Source? @SagarV

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298743/228134

Comment: also Nick confirmed it